# using iScroll 4 scroll the last element to the start position of first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, css, iscroll4

I am now using iScroll 4 from http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 to enable scrolling in touch devices.The problem is that the last element is not coming proper. I want the last element to scroll till the start position of the scroll. I am not understanding how to make it work. The last element is not coming to the center of the screen width. I have positioned the first element to the center of screen. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to do `(Screen width - Element width) + (Number of elements*Element width)` to bring the last element to the start position of the scroll. Here in my case center of the screen.